# R eliminate multiple lookups in a dictionary

Tags: r

I have a dictionary (table table with 2 columns) where some of the values match some of the keys.  In those situations, I want to replace the values with the value from the key they point to.

Example:

```
Key,   Value
"aa",  "ac"
"ab",  "ba"
"ac",  "ad"
"ad",  "da"
"ae",  "ac"
```

What I'm trying to produce:

```
Key,   Value
"aa",  "da"
"ab",  "ba"
"ac",  "da"
"ad",  "da"
"ae",  "da"
```

What I have tried:

```
dict <- data.frame(key=c("aa","ab","ac","ad","ae"),value=c("ac","ba","ad","da","ac"))
repeat {
    needs_replacing <- dict[dict$Value %in% dict$Key,]
    if(nrow(needs_replacing) == 0) {
        break;
    }
    replacements <- dict[dict$Key %in% needs_replacing$Value,]
    dict[dict$Value %in% dict$Key,]$Value <- replacements[?????,]$Value
}
```

The problem I'm having is that `replacements` only has 3 values on the first iteration, but I'm trying to expand it to replace 4 values.  I know you can subset it with indexes, but getting them is kind of a pain, and I'm just not sure if there is a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We just need to adjust the loop. In the `replacements` expression, `match` is better than `%in%` because it will return the index of matches whereas the latter will return logicals agnostic of location:

```
repeat {
  needs_replacing <- dict$value[dict$value %in% dict$key]
  if(length(needs_replacing) == 0) {
    break;
  }
  replacements <- dict$value[match(needs_replacing, dict$key)]
  dict$value[dict$value %in% dict$key] <- replacements
}
dict
#   key value
# 1  aa    da
# 2  ab    ba
# 3  ac    da
# 4  ad    da
# 5  ae    da
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work, It produces the desired output.

```
while(length(dict[dict$Value %in% dict$Key, "Value"]) > 0) {
  dict[dict$Value %in% dict$Key, "Value"] <- 
  dict[match(dict[dict$Value %in% dict$Key, "Value"], dict$Key), "Value"]
}
```